# I have made an entry for the server alias in my .conf file in '/etc/apache2/example.com.conf' but still it doesn't work with www in the browser

Tags: apache2

My example.com directory is in `/var/www/html/example.com` and I am running it on localhost.

The `example.com.conf` file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I made an entry in the hosts file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

I can access the website in the browser using `example.com` but when I try to access `www.example.com` it says could not connect. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add the `www` prefix in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
```

Comment: your solution works. but, www.example.com is the alias. why do we make an entry for it in the hosts file rather than for example.com?

Comment: any alias you set in hosts file is used by browser to get data. `example.com` is not equals to `www.example.com`. by default when the browser could not find `example.com` will uses `www.example.com`, but not vice versa...